# Erro Firebird com Entity Framework e C#

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework-6, firebird

Estou tentando usar o Firebird com Entity Framework no C#, mas quando crio relacionamentos e tento dar Update-Database na Migration dá esse erro:

> Type is not resolved for member 'FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbException,FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient, Version=4.10.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3750abcc3150b00c'.

Meu App.config está assim:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
</configSections>
<startup>
  <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
</startup>
<entityFramework>
  <defaultConnectionFactory type="FirebirdSql.Data.EntityFramework6.FbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework.Firebird" />
  <providers>
     <provider invariantName="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient" type="FirebirdSql.Data.EntityFramework6.FbProviderServices, EntityFramework.Firebird" />
     <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
  </providers>
</entityFramework>
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient" publicKeyToken="3750abcc3150b00c" culture="neutral" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.5.0.0" newVersion="4.5.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
        <remove invariant="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient" />
        <add name="FirebirdClient Data Provider" invariant="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Firebird" type="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FirebirdClientFactory, FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
</configuration>
```

Existe alguma solução?

Comment: Como está seu `Web.config`?

Comment: No caso eu uso App.config, adicionei ele na pergunta.

Comment: Por que tem dois providers no `entityFramework`?

Comment: Cara eu não sei, porque o app.config foi gerado automaticamente e eu nem mudei nada.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez quando você instala o EF ele registra automaticamente o SqlClient, quando instala o Firebird ele instala o segundo.

Comment: @AndréMoraisMartins qual versão do EF você está utilizando ?

Comment: Acho que seu `FirebirdClient` esta na `VS 6` e seu `NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2"`

Comment: Seguindo um tutorial que eu achei na internet, eu baixei 3 pacotes pelo nuget: EntityFramework (Versão 6.1.3), FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient e EntityFramework.Firebird (Ambos em versão 4.10.0)